# nested attributes upload multiple photos in ror with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, paperclip, nested-forms, nested-attributes

i try to upload photos put doesnt seems to working. **FOR MANY PHOTOS**

in view>building>_form

```
<%= form_for(@building, :html=>{:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <% if @building.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@building.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this building from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @building.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %><br />
    <%= f.select :status, Building::STATUS, :prompt=>'Select status of the building' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 10 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :location %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :location %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <h3>Tasks</h3>
  <% f.fields_for :tasks do |task_form| -%>
    <%= render :partial => 'task', :locals => { :form => task_form } %>
  <% end -%>


  <%= add_photo(f) %>

   <%= f.file_field :foto%>

      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

in view>building>_task

```
    <div class="task">
      <p>
        <%= form.label :name %>
        <%= form.text_field :name, :size => 15 %>
        <%= remove_task_link( form ) %>
      </p>
    </div>

in helpers>building_helpers

module BuildingsHelper

def add_photo(form_builder)
  link_to_function "add", :id  => "add_photo" do |page|
  form_builder.fields_for :tasks, Task.new, :child_index => 'NEW_RECORD' do |f|
        html = render(:partial => 'task', :locals => { :form => f })
        page << "$('tasks').insert({ bottom: '#{escape_javascript(html)}'.replace(/NEW_RECORD/g, new Date().getTime()) });"
       end
  end
end

   def remove_task_link(form_builder)
    if form_builder.object.new_record?
      # If the task is a new record, we can just remove the div from the dom
      link_to_function("remove", "$(this).up('.task').remove();");
    else
      # However if it's a "real" record it has to be deleted from the database,
      # for this reason the new fields_for, accept_nested_attributes helpers give us _delete,
      # a virtual attribute that tells rails to delete the child record.
      form_builder.hidden_field(:_delete) +
      link_to_function("remove", "$(this).up('.task').hide(); $(this).previous().value = '1'")
    end
  end
end
```

in controller>building

```
 def new
    @building = Building.new
    2.times { @building.tasks.build }
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @building }
    end
  end

  # GET /buildings/1/edit
  def edit
    @building = Building.find(params[:id])
    2.times { @building.tasks.build }
  end
```

in view>layout>application

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Welcome to koshbay</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

model>task

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :building_id, :name 
  belongs_to :project
has_attached_file :foto, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>",
                      :thumb => "100x100>" , 
                     :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"}

end
```

model>building

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :price, :status, :title ,:location, `:foto`

  has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy
  # This is new!
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :allow_destroy => true
 end
```

UPDATE 1 db tables

db>create_task

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :building_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

db> create_buildings

```
class CreateBuildings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :buildings do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :location     
      t.string :status
      t.text :description
      t.decimal :price, :precision=>8, :scale => 2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

UPDATE 2

**i thing the problem is in _task.html.erb**

UPDATE 3

i have run rails g paperclip building foto

and now in db i have

```
class AddAttachmentFotoToBuildings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :buildings do |t|
      t.has_attached_file :foto
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :buildings, :foto
  end
end
```

i am using this example
'http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=28447'

i dont get any error and i cant see anything that i can put photo to upload it.when i press the add button is not making anything.

any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: To do it in Rails (cause i don't know actually what your code is representing), you would have to add the paperclip gem: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip Follow the documentation and install the imageMagick,add the Paperclip.options line...add the validations, update the view to upload it and always remember to restart the server after installing new gems (don't forget to run bundle install also).

Comment: https://github.com/kosh8884/projectproperties.git

to can add a building i have username and pass: kosh , kosh4ever

Comment: yes, i will look at it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here is what i have done to work with **nested attributes**.
to do this you need to 2 plug in 1)paperclip 2)imagemagick

in gemfile add the row

gem 'paperclip'

then run in cmd: bundle install

and then run gem install rmagick //<------- i thing will work. i forgot

step-by-step

** p.s.: building is the relation one(building) to (many)photos **

step 1 :i create a table with the commant: rails g model buildingphoto building_id:integer

db

```
class CreateBuildingPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :building_photos do |t|
      t.integer :building_id


      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

step 2: commant>rails g paperclip buildingphoto photo

db

```
class AddAttachmentPhotoToBuildingPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :building_photos do |t|
      t.has_attached_file :photo
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :building_photos, :photo
  end
end
```

when finish the step 2 run: rake db:migrate

in model>buildingphoto

```
class BuildingPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :building_id , :photo
  belongs_to :building

    has_many :photo

    has_attached_file :photo

end
```

in model>building

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :building_photos_attributes

  has_many :building_photos, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :building_photos
end
```

in controller>buildingcontroller

```
def new
    @building = Building.new

    4.times { @building.building_photos.build }
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @building }
    end
  end
```

in views>building>_buildingphoto.html.erb // i creat it

```
 <%= f.label :photo %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
```

in views>building>_form.html.erb // i add this line

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.fields_for :building_photos do |builder| %>
    <%= render "buildingphoto", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
```

in config>environments>development.rb // Tell Paperclip where to find your ImageMagick installation (not always required)

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"
```

to view the photos that you have upload

```
<% building.building_photos.each do |photo| %>
        <%= link_to (image_tag (photo.photo.url)), building %>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can see your project here:

**https://github.com/DamirSvrtan/For-mario**

you can clone it from there. Anyways, to give you the details:

1.You didn't include this line to your `config/environments/development.rb:`

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

You can see that i put that line there and that it is actually `"/usr/bin"`

Run the which convert command, what you get, just strip off the last `'/convert'` from it and put it in the `development.rb` file.

2.You had the foto attributes in your building model but your has_attached in your task model. I fixed that also. I've also changed your view and removed the nested attribute to handle the photo, rather I've made the building form to handle it.
I accidentally erased the nested attribute part in the form so just get it back, two lines i think.

3.For some reason your code won't work with "styles" part of the has_attachment. I really don't know why that is, cause all of mine have so far worked perfectly with it.
I tried to fix it but i couldn't find the solution. Some other people also had the same problem on stackoverflow, maybe it's some ruby-rails version thingy. Nothing else comes to my mind. If you don't find a solution to that, you can still 'breath' with it but, maybe ask someone again here on SO why that is happening.

4.I changed the paperclip gem to be:

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
```

5.Hope you will understand all the changes I made. You can accept the code or not, your wish.

Comment: thx for the fix. but the thing is that i dont want it only for 1 photo put many photos...for one i had done it but for many fotos is the problem..this is why i make task and nested attribute..any ideas?

Comment: for every photo you want to put in you would need additional columns in your table buildings. or make a extra table and relate it to the buildings table.

Comment: maybe you can try it with that, i have never worked with nested attributes. I overlooked the nested_attributes part, but you COULD HAVE MENTIONED IT IN THE QUESTION!! make your questions more clear next time

Comment: in the example that i have used and i have post the link it was for many photos....

Comment: as i said, yeah i have overlooked that..sorry it is my mistake but next time formulate the question a little bit better.

Comment: i could try to help you once i get a hold of nested_attributes and what they are. What is this, something for school?

Comment: one thing for sure. the migration to the building model is wrong. it should be for the task.

Comment: at least this time you gave me a up vote haha. You will have to do it with nested attributes. remove your last migration with the rollback, it will remove the foto attributes from your database. add it to the `Task` table. actually, please name your tables normally. maybe like `BuildingPhoto`. see the tutorial here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
Now you have set up the whole paperclip gem and you only have to figure out the nested form. Remember to migrate everything, and don't put the `styles` with `has_attached`.

Comment: fainaly i did it!!!!!!!!! thx for the help! if you want to see how i will post it later when i fix some view thing! and again thanks with out your help i will not make it.

Comment: haha okay, i am really glad you made it! as a sign of appreciation do accept the answer :)